# Calling multiple make files in multiple folders at same time for parallel compilation of files at each folder

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automake

I have multiple **folders/modules** with multiple source files .
Each folder will have their own make files to compile the source code.

Is it possible to call all the make files at same time from a main make/batch file? so that source code from all folders get compiled in parallel.

At last I can collect all the .o files & create the respective libraries.

Reason for above question : Usually from a main batch file, I will `cd` into each folder & call `make -j`. But in one case my compiler(very old) is throwing errors when `-j` option is used.

Comment: To achieve that I recommend you to use *prorab* template library for non-recursive make, here is the tutorial: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Comment: I would also recommend going for a non-recursive solution. If you can upgrade to GNU make 3.81, prorab is probably a good starting point. Otherwise I would recommend reading [Writing a large build system with GNU make](http://david.rothlis.net/large-gnu-make/) or [Recursive make Reloaded](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2101/) to get started. There are lots of non-recursive make templates and frameworks but they won't necessarily be helpful for your needs.

Comment: btw, the compiler will *never* see the `-j` flag, as this is a `make` flag. maybe you can upgrade your `make`?